# Parse csproj file using cake's ParseProject

Tags: cakebuild

Create minimal repro project:

```bash
dotnet new classlib --no-restore --output /tmp/Foo
cd /tmp/Foo
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install cake.tool
touch build.cake
```

Put this minimal script in `build.cake`:

```
Task("Default").Does(() => {
  var file = "./Foo.csproj";
  Information(FileExists(file).ToString());
  var props = ParseProject(file);
});
RunTarget("Default");
```

Run it:

```
dotnet cake
```

Result:

```
========================================
Default
========================================
True
An error occurred when executing task 'Default'.
Error: Failed to parse project properties
```

Surely this minimal script should succeed - have I made a mistake, or is this a bug?

My environment: linux, dotnet 6.0.302.

Comment: You can raise the verbosity of the output to maximum by calling cake like `dotnet cake --verbosity=diagnostic` and see if that brings you closer to the error.

Comment: @Nils Thanks, that's a good idea! I just did that and it gives me a large stacktrace. Unfortunately there's nothing in there related to my code - it's all internal cake stuff which I don't understand. I think it could be a bug, but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of box, the `ParseProject` alias within Cake (version 2.2.0), only knows how to parse Visual Studio Project files that are using the "old" format.

Since the Visual Studio Project file that you are creating is using the "new" format (i.e. it was generated using the dotnet CLI, and is targetting .NET Core), the `ParseProject` in Cake will not be able to recognise it.

There is however an alternative `ParseProject` alias in the Cake.Incubator addin that can do what you want.  You can make use of this by doing:

```
#addin nuget:?package=Cake.Incubator&version=7.0.0

Task("Default").Does(() => {
  var file = "./cake-test.csproj";
  Information(FileExists(file).ToString());
  var props = ParseProject(file, "Release");
});

RunTarget("Default");
```

Result:

```bash
========================================
Default
========================================
True

Task                          Duration
--------------------------------------------------
Default                       00:00:00.0496415
--------------------------------------------------
Total:                        00:00:00.0496415
```

At some point, the work in the Cake.Incubator addin will likely be merged into Cake, and will ship as a new version, however, for now, you will need to bring in the addin directly.